# Extracting text from a xml file

Tags: xml, python-3.4

I am trying to extract the text from an XML file but I am not getting the results I expect.

This is a fragment of the XML I am trying to parse to illustrate my problem:

```xml
<texto_Quijote_I>
<bloque nombre="prologo">
<autor>
Desocupado lector: sin juramento me podrás creer que quisiera que este;
como será poner, tratando de libertad y cautiverio:
<cita_latin>   Non bene pro toto libertas venditur auro.</cita_latin>
Y luego, en el margen, citar a Horacio, o a quien lo dijo. Si tratáredes
del poder de la muerte, acudir luego con:
<cita_latin>
   Pallida mors aequo pulsat pede pauperum tabernas,
   Regumque turres.
</cita_latin>
Si de la amistad y amor que Dios manda que se tenga al enemigo, entraros
luego al punto por la Escritura Divina, que lo podéis hacer con tantico de
curiosidad, y decir las palabras, por lo menos, del mismo Dios:
<cita_latin>Ego autem dico vobis: diligite inimicos vestros</cita_latin>. 
Si tratáredes de malos pensamientos,
acudid con el Evangelio: 
<cita_latin>De corde exeunt cogitationes malae</cita_latin>. 
Si de la instabilidad de los amigos, ahí está Catón, que os dará su dístico:
<cita_latin>
   Donec eris felix, multos numerabis amicos,
   tempora si fuerint nubila, solus eris.
</cita_latin>
Y con estos latinicos y otros tales os tendrán siquiera por gramático, que
Y con esto, Dios te dé salud, y a mí no olvide. Vale.
</autor>
</bloque>
</texto_Quijote_I>
```

I am trying to extract all the text between certain tags. So for example to obtain all the text between `<autor>..</autor>` tags, I was trying this:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
text = ""
for n in root.findall(".//autor"):
    text += n.text
```

But when I check the string, I only get:

```
"Desocupado lector: sin juramento me podrás creer que quisiera que este;
como será poner, tratando de libertad y cautiverio:"
```

Is this how it should work? I was expecting to get all the text between `<autor>` and `</autor>`.

Comment: The documentation says that text only shows the text content of the tag. The other stuff are not part of the <autor> text (set and subset theory?):
`Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. Element.find() finds the first child with a particular tag, and Element.text accesses the element’s text content. Element.get() accesses the element’s attributes:`

Also, `The xml.etree.ElementTree module is not secure against maliciously constructed data. If you need to parse untrusted or unauthenticated data see XML vulnerabilities.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta iterate to the children and collect the texts from there, too.

Also, I utilized "tail" because it captures information between the tags. Quoting from the documentation:

> If the element is created from an XML file, the text attribute holds
>   either the text between the element’s start tag and its first child or
>   end tag, or None, and the ***tail attribute holds either the text between
>   the element’s end tag and the next tag, or None.***

```
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
text = ""
for n in root.findall(".//autor"):
    text += n.text
    text += n.tail
    for x in n:
        text += x.text
        text += x.tail

print text
```

Result

```
Desocupado lector: sin juramento me podrás creer que quisiera que este;
como será poner, tratando de libertad y cautiverio:

   Non bene pro toto libertas venditur auro.
Y luego, en el margen, citar a Horacio, o a quien lo dijo. Si tratáredes
del poder de la muerte, acudir luego con:

   Pallida mors aequo pulsat pede pauperum tabernas,
   Regumque turres.

Si de la amistad y amor que Dios manda que se tenga al enemigo, entraros
luego al punto por la Escritura Divina, que lo podéis hacer con tantico de
curiosidad, y decir las palabras, por lo menos, del mismo Dios:
Ego autem dico vobis: diligite inimicos vestros. 
Si tratáredes de malos pensamientos,
acudid con el Evangelio: 
De corde exeunt cogitationes malae. 
Si de la instabilidad de los amigos, ahí está Catón, que os dará su dístico:

   Donec eris felix, multos numerabis amicos,
   tempora si fuerint nubila, solus eris.

Y con estos latinicos y otros tales os tendrán siquiera por gramático, que
Y con esto, Dios te dé salud, y a mí no olvide. Vale.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that "tail" method is extracting the text that I wanted.